# create sheet from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am able to creat sheet using :

[NSApp beginSheet:scorePanel modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:self didEndSelector: NULL contextInfo:nil];

I can create sheet when I call this command directly.
But when I call the method holding this command from other class I am not able to open sheet getting error :

*** Assertion failure in -[NSApplication _commonBeginModalSessionForWindow:relativeToWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.35/AppKit.subproj/NSApplication.m:3100
2011-05-06 18:52:43.282 CoreAnimationWizard[5647:903] Modal session requires modal window

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "calling directly" and "from another class". Which object is making this call in the first case?

Comment: i want to open sheet by calling the method from another class...

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/oct/msg00748.html i am having the same as this one

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is because the window is not hooked up to File's Owner. If the window isn't set you will get that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new reference outlet to File Owner's window.